# nesting css class for sprite image

Tags: css, css-sprites

I'm just bit confused on css Id/class nesting.
sample code below:

```
1) #sprit-img {
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-image:url(ig-sprite.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin:5px;
    }
2) #sprit-img a.brew{
    background-position:2px 0px;}  
3) #sprit-img a.scc{
    background-position:-295px 2px;}
```

in page i used like

```
4) <div id="sprit-img><a class="brew"></a>...</div> `
```

now i want to use it like

```
5) <div class="sprit-img"><a class="brew"></a> <span class="scc"></span></div>`
```

Questions

1. is it necessary to give anchor or any element tag in code line **2 and 3**?
2. what would be optimal way to get line 5(if Q1 is true, to have in css class i removed # and place . but not working in my page)?   is this correct

--

```
6) .sprit-img{.....same code..}  
    .brew{...same position..}  
    .scc{..same postion...}
```

and use it like in line 5  or
 this is correct

```
7) .sprit-img{.....same code..}  
    .sprit-img .brew{...same position..}  `
```

Thanks.

---

edit: I tried some mix put background-image from **sprit-img to brew and scc** and found that if i put style as in 6 the html part should be like
`<div class="anything"><span class="sprit-img brew"></span></div>`
 and  if i put style like in 7  html part should be like
 `<div class="sprit-img"><span class="sprit-img brew"></span></div>`
but could not make it like 5 any idea ...

Comment: I corrected your code formatting but you seem to have reverted it, please try to get it right otherwise question is difficult to understand.

Comment: I also updated the code formatting. ;)

Comment: Even after formatting the code, I'm not entirely clean on the question. Some possibilities: you have a lot of spelling differences between your CSS and HTML. Check your IDs vs. Classes. Be sure your sprite containers are display: block (not inline). No, you don't need to use a.class and can use .class by itself. a.class is just more specific that .class.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, @roryf I have not reverted it, may be we both edited at the same time, actually i did try to format but that was what best i could have done.@DA spelling brew and bew I've corrected them but may be missed it here  in working environment I'm using eclipse so possibility is just local here if any on coping/writing out,I'll be careful on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q.1:   No.

Q.2:

You need a way to target both types of things inside your div at once in order to apply the same bg image,  as well as a way to differentiate them. There are numerous solutions.

As long as you're sure  that anything nested inside sprit-img should take the background, you could do this:

```
<div class="sprit-img">
    <a class="brew"></a> <span class="scc"></span>
</div>

#sprit-img * { background-image:url(ig-sprite.png) };
#sprit-img .bew { background-position:2px 0px }
#sprit-img .scc { background-position:-295px 2px; }
```

(note: * is the universal selector)

...though that could get you in trouble if you need any markup inside of those elements (everything would take the background image, and it would be a funky jumble)

So, if you are sure all child elements (nested only 1 level down) should take the background, but nothing inside of those elements should, then you can use the child selector ( > ) like this:

```
<div class="sprit-img">
    <a class="brew"><span> some text></span>some other text</a> 
    <span class="scc">more text <strong>something important</strong></span><
</div>

#sprit-img > * { background-image:url(ig-sprite.png) };
#sprit-img .bew { background-position:2px 0px }
#sprit-img .scc { background-position:-295px 2px; }
```

if you want to avoid the universal selector (rendering could be slow on older machines or with earlier browser versions), you could alternatively use (with line 5 markup):

```
#sprit-img > a, #sprit-img > span { background-image:url(ig-sprite.png) };
#sprit-img .bew { background-position:2px 0px }
#sprit-img .scc { background-position:-295px 2px; }
```

...which would then only apply to anchors and spans inside of an element with id="sprit-img"

Or you coulld avoid tag-names altogether (if you are super render-speed conscious)  (with line 5 markup)

```
#sprit-img .bew, #sprit-img .scc { background-image:url(ig-sprite.png) };
#sprit-img .bew { background-position:2px 0px }
#sprit-img .scc { background-position:-295px 2px; }
```

...which illustrates why the answer to your first question is "no"

Comment: Thanks it sound good to me specially the point about speed. i believe i should be using . instead of # as I don't want to make it id specific. and i guess line 5 in question can't be achieved with class only format(is it?) as you mentioned it will jumble up.

Comment: @rain: "jumbling up" would happen if you use the universal selector (asterisk) as a descendent element in the selector (using just a space, not > to separate it from #spirit-img), and then put more things inside of the <a> and <span> tags, because then you're saying "put this bg image on every single element found anywhere inside of #sprit-img, no matter how deeply nested". And that could look kaleidoscopic. You absolutely *can* use line 5 markup for what you want -- either of the last 2 sets of CSS  examples should work with that. (NOTE: you didn't include the closing </div> in your sample.)

Comment: Thanks, line 5 markup would be possible with ID selector but is it possible with class selectors as well?

Comment: @rain: oh -- didn't even notice that "sprit-img" was a class. Yes, just use:  .sprit-img .bew, .sprit-img .scc{ background-image:url(ig-sprite.png) }   I'm I getting your question right?

Answer (score 0):

`#` is an ID selector, `.` is a class selector. So you could change to:

```
.sprit-img {...}  
.sprit-img .brew {...}  
.sprit-img .scc {...}
```

and

```
<div class="sprit-img"><a class="brew"></a> <span class="scc"></span></div>
```

However, the real problem is your trying to use non-cascading properties in `.sprit-img` on the child elements. The first selector should be changed to `.sprit-img .brew, .sprit-img .scc`

Comment: Thanks but it only showed the first image in sprite image set. and all other inside div were not rendered at all.